# Pyspark: How to group rows into N groups?

Tags: pyspark

I am performing a `df.groupBy().apply()` in my pyspark script and want to create a custom column that has grouped all my rows into N (as even as possible, so rows/n) groups. That why, I can ensure the number of groups sent to my udf function everytime the script runs.

How can I do this using pyspark?

Comment: can you add a sample input and your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an exact split, then you need windowing

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
#Test data
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4),(3,2,5,4),(5,3,7,5),(7,3,9,5),(1,2,3,4),(3,2,5,4),(5,3,7,5),(7,3,9,5),(1,2,3,4),(3,2,5,4),(5,3,7,5),(7,3,9,5),(1,2,3,4),(3,2,5,4),(5,3,7,5),(7,3,9,5)],schema=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
w=Window.orderBy(F.lit(1))
tst_mod = tst.withColumn("id",(F.row_number().over(w))%3) # 3 is the group size in this example

tst_mod.show()
+----+----+----+----+---+
|col1|col2|col3|col4| id|
+----+----+----+----+---+
|   5|   3|   7|   5|  1|
|   3|   2|   5|   4|  2|
|   5|   3|   7|   5|  0|
|   7|   3|   9|   5|  1|
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  2|
|   7|   3|   9|   5|  0|
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  1|
|   5|   3|   7|   5|  2|
|   7|   3|   9|   5|  0|
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  1|
|   3|   2|   5|   4|  2|
|   5|   3|   7|   5|  0|
|   3|   2|   5|   4|  1|
|   7|   3|   9|   5|  2|
|   3|   2|   5|   4|  0|
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  1|
+----+----+----+----+---+

tst_mod.groupby('id').count().show()
+---+-----+
| id|count|
+---+-----+
|  1|    6|
|  2|    5|
|  0|    5|
+---+-----+
```

If you are ok with a normal distribution, then you can try a technique called salting

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
#Test data
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4),(3,2,5,4),(5,3,7,5),(7,3,9,5),(1,2,3,4),(3,2,5,4),(5,3,7,5),(7,3,9,5),(1,2,3,4),(3,2,5,4),(5,3,7,5),(7,3,9,5),(1,2,3,4),(3,2,5,4),(5,3,7,5),(7,3,9,5)],schema=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
tst_salt= tst.withColumn("salt", F.rand(seed=10)*3)
```

If you groupby the column salt, you will have a normally distributed group

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! Will give this a go.